# Connecting to an Interbase Database File via C#

Tags: database-connection, interbase

All --
        I am trying to export data from an Interbase Version 5 database file by using the following connection string:

```
Provider=LCPI.IBProvider;Location=\"<Path To Database>";User ID=******;Password=*****;ctype=win1251"
```

I have downloaded and installed the from the [IBProvider](http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/index.html) website. I am getting the following error:

```
The 'LCPI.IBProvider' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

I tried manually registering the _IBProvider_v3_vc10_w64_lite_trial_i.dll file but no luck.

Ok, so here is my question can I connect to this database file similarly to a FoxPro database file without having the database software installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer, I had to download the latest version of [FireBird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) database engine and then attach the database. Then I downloaded the [EMS SQL Manager for InterBase/Firebird](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/ibfb/manager) GUI because I didn't want to bother with using the ISQL command line application.